# OSX 10.11 default apache process can not run node commands in php

Tags: php, macos, apache, osx-elcapitan

This issue existed in 10.10 but came back with 10.11
the fix in 10.10 was to modify /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist and adding the following key

```
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin</string>
    </dict>
```

10.11 the file is locked down by the system.
I've tried creating my own version of the file in /Library/LaunchDaemons and then using launchctl to unload the System version and load mine.

this works but fails to hold on a reboot.
adding the -w option doesn't help either with holding through a reboot.

Is there another option besides disabling the system protection and modifying the file in the system folder?
I'd like a solution that holds through apple updates.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure this out with the following:

```
sudo cp /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apachecustom.httpd.plist
```

Edit this custom version. 
Be sure to update the label key with the new file name.

Turn off the old version with

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

turn on the new version with

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apachecustom.httpd.plist
```